# Using SQL to group metrics into dimensions - DataStudio

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I am trying to group metrics into dimensions as follows:

```
+--------+-------+
|  Meal  | Score |
+--------+-------+
| Burger |     4 |
| Chips  |     4 |
| Beans  |     2 |
+--------+-------+

+-------+-------+
| Score | Count |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     0 |
|     2 |     1 |
|     3 |     0 |
|     4 |     2 |
|     5 |     0 |
+-------+-------+
```

I will then be able to further group these in data studio as follows:

```
Low Score (1-3)
High Score (4-5)
```

I have tried the following SQL query on my table, but it comes up with an error:

```
SELECT COUNT(Meal), Score
FROM [table]
GROUP BY Score
```

Comment: show the exact error message

Comment: Your table is called 'table'??

Comment: No, my table is not actually called table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
SELECT Score, COUNT(Score) as Count
FROM table
GROUP BY Score
ORDER BY Score
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference adding a Google Data Studio (as it's also tagged) suggestion to achieve the outcome with the original Data Set.

The [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below groups a `Score` between 1 to 3 as `Low Score`, 4 to 5 as `High Score` and ELSE values as `Unclassified Score`:

```
CASE
  WHEN Score >= 1 AND Score <= 3 THEN "Low Score"
  WHEN Score >= 4 AND Score <= 5 THEN "High Score"
  ELSE "Unclassified Score"
END
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/8a4b9ee6-51ab-475a-a788-57923d33e1ae) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]